# Error in iOS 6 after adding GameCenter to a landscape-only cocos2d app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, orientation, game-center

I'm having the issue described here:
https://devforums.apple.com/thread/165384?tstart=0
Where my app crashes trying to load the GameCenter login screen because the screen is in portrait and my app only supports landscape.
I've tried every solution described in the above thread, as well as all the solutions on the following thread:
[Crash on presenting UIImagePickerController under iOS 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522491/crash-on-presenting-uiimagepickercontroller-under-ios6/12575058#12575058)
And here:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/36639

None of the solutions work.  Either the crash still occurs, or the login works fine, and either my app then freely rotates between landscape and portrait, or it locks itself into portrait and screws up the entire UI.

What I want is for the GameCenter login to work in portrait, and then for everything else in the app to occur in landscape.

Here are all the rotation methods contained in my app.  These are the ones from the myNavigationController implementation in appdelegate.m:

```
    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    // iPhone only
    if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

    // iPad only
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // iPhone only
    if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);

    // iPad only
    // iPhone only
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}


-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{

    return NO;
 }
```

And from the AppController implementation in appDelegate.m:

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Contained in RootViewController.m:

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
        return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}


- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return NO;
    }


#if GAME_AUTOROTATION==kGameAutorotationNone
    return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );

#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION==kGameAutorotationCCDirector
    if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    } else if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    }


#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
#else
#error Unknown value in GAME_AUTOROTATION

#endif // GAME_AUTOROTATION
    // Shold not happen
    return NO;
}

kGameAutorotationUIViewController

#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;

    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        rect = screenRect;

    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        rect.size = CGSizeMake( screenRect.size.height, screenRect.size.width );
    }


    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    UIView *glView = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] view];;
    float contentScaleFactor = [director contentScaleFactor];

    if( contentScaleFactor != 1 ) {
        rect.size.width *= contentScaleFactor;
        rect.size.height *= contentScaleFactor;
    }
    glView.frame = rect;
}
#endif // GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just answered this question a few days ago here: 
[Cocos 2d 2.0 shouldAutorotate not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718761/cocos-2d-2-0-shouldautorotate-not-working/13736022#13736022)

There are instructions on what you need to do to get this to work in that answer.  Hope this helps!

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Wish I'd found that thread before I spent all that time going through all the stuff in the other three threads that didn't work.