# iAd banner not clickable if banner moves

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, iad

I have an iAd banner working in a Cocos2d app.

Here's the code for a CCLayer subclass I made to show ads. On DidLoad, the add becomes visible and the bottom menu slides up to compensate.

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {
        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, size.height -32, 320, 32);

        ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape];

        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
        [controller.view addSubview:adView];
        adView.delegate = self;

        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:controller.view];
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] setNeedsLayout]; // I was told this would fix it, but it fails to.
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if (!bannerIsVisible)
    {
        NSLog(@"bannerViewDidLoadAd");
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -32); //the offending line

        self.position = ccpAdd(ccp(0, 32), self.position);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        bannerIsVisible = YES;


    }
}
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (bannerIsVisible)
    {
        NSLog(@"bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:");
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 32); //the other offending line
        self.position = ccpAdd(ccp(0, -32), self.position);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }

}
```

When those lines are disabled, the banner is clickable, but the ugly white banner is visible. What's up with this? How do I fix or get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cocos2d_2.0_iAd_Sample](https://github.com/gururajios/Cocos2d-iAd.git)

[Cocos2d_3.0_iAd_Sample](https://app.box.com/s/fr5ya0hyf322gfd7gntx)

In your scene do this.

­

```
-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
       
     mIAd = [[MyiAd alloc] init];
 
}
     
-(void)play
{
    [self hideAdsBanner];
}
```

```
-­(void)hideAdsBanner
{
    if(mIAd)
    [mIAd RemoveiAd ];
 
}
 
­-(void)onExit
{
    if(mIAd)
    {
        [mIAd release];
        mIAd = nil;
    }
    [super onExit];
 
}
```