# How to add iad in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, iad

Does anyone have any idea how to put an iAd banner ad in a **cocos2d** game (for ios - iphone)?

Please refer me to any useful tutorials/guides (please make sure they are up to date though) or explain below.

Any help is appreciated but please include code/steps!

Comment: http://highoncoding.com/Articles/751_Implementing_iAd_on_Cocos2d_Application.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here is my Cocos2d_2.0-iAd banner sample](https://github.com/gururajios/Cocos2d-iAd.git)

[Cocos2d 3.0 iAd Banner Sample](https://app.box.com/s/fr5ya0hyf322gfd7gntx)

Also you can see here : [iAd Banner for Cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890479/iad-banner-not-clickable-if-banner-moves/14918044#14918044)

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but when I add the new class (MyiAd), what type of class does it need to be (Objective C or cocos2d Node?) and what does it need to be a subclass of.

Comment: Also, when you say add to the scene (in linked answer), does that mean just put the code in the HelloWorldLayer.h file?

Comment: in githug I added working sample..refer that. just drag those MyiAd.h and MyiAd.mm to your project.