# iAd banner position is wrong on iPhone 6/6 Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iad

I'm trying to optimize my SpriteKit App for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus but the iAd banner position is wrong and I can't change it. It works great on 4" or 3.5" iPhones but on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus the banner isn't at the bottom, it is a bit above it.

Also, I've been searching for this problem in google. There were many solutions but none of them worked for me.

I'm using following code for the iAd banner in my ViewController.m file:

```
//iAd
#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(screen);

    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, height-banner.frame.size.height);
    //Changing the Y-position doesn't change the banner's position

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Ads_savedata"] == NO)
        [banner setAlpha:0];
    else
        [banner setAlpha:1];

    [banner updateConstraints];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

For me, it looks like the following line doesn't affect the banner's position.

```
banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, height-banner.frame.size.height);
```

I hope someone can help me with that problem. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess its screen width and height problem. Try this once

```
float SW;
float SH;
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
if (( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]<8)  && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
{
    SW = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    SH = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
}
else
{
    SW = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    SH = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but it doesn't work. Also I'm using the App in Portrait only.

Comment: Check sample iAd project in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815777/how-to-add-iad-in-cocos2d/17816415#17816415

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was a able to solve the problem with help of your iAd projects. For others with the same problem: Don't use the iAd BannerView by add it in the Main.storyboard. You have to create the iAd banner programmatically (iAd doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html)